# menu selected and ie6 .. again

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

here is the page : http://pfibco.ca/01-accueil-fra.php

I try to block hover highlight the menu... work almost fine

just the selected class dont apply... why ?

```
#menu ul li a .selected{
```

and the worst... the menu is completely destroy in ie6, why ?
i used the block propriety.. no choice for the hover...

```
display: block;
```

how to fix that ?

Comment: I found THAT AMAZING LINK TODAY ....http://css-tricks.com/keep-margins-out-of-link-lists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the selected problem:

```
#menu ul li.selected a {
```

The HTML has the `selected` class on the `<li>` so the CSS should match that.

I can't help you with IE6 though, it destroys a lot of things and my nerves are one of those things.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your IE 6 issues:

1. Each menu li tag seems having a style rule for line-height : 15.76pt, which is not found in other browsers. I guess IE6 incorrectly inherit the style from ancestor tag, maybe you can check you CSS file.
2. The border doesn't seem to work in each link, you can try to apply the border to its parent li tag instead of the anchor itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you got hurry, you can use a litle hack for IE6 ( I'm got red now =X ).

```
/* hack for IE6 */
* html #menu ul li {
    border: 1px solid #BFAF98;
    border-top: none;
```

}

I think it's works fine.